# Getting as Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 in cmd and html report

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

After execution of test getting as **Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ygL3.png)

After html report got generated and when I look into the report it shows as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98AVE.png)

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

It means that your test execution failed somewhere somehow hence none of [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) was executed and there are no results.

The most common problems are:

- not providing CSV file referenced in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- missing [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) used in the test

You need to take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging), normally it contains enough information to guess what went wrong and what needs to be fixed.